# Direction of conflict between two rotated rectangles

Tags: java, geometry, collision-detection

I am currently trying to create an anti-collision algorithm with rotated 3D rectangle boxes (wireframes). My system should limit the speed of the two rectangles in the direction where there might be a collision (speed limit in x negative direction, x positive dir, y neg dir, y pos dir, z neg and z positive direction). Each rectangle will be evaluated individually.

Lets say there is a overlap between two individual rectangles in the XZ plane. This scenario could lead to a collision in the Y direction. I need to know a good way of calculating which direction I should limit? Its easy if the two rectangles are outside each others boundary boxes, then its only to compare rectangle 1 min Y vs rectangle 2 max Y and so on, but the problem is when one of the rectangles are rotated around the X-axis. Then you might have a collision in several directions.

I need a unique way to detect the direction(s) where the rectangle should have speed limitation(s).

Br
saadne

Comment: There can only be a collision if the rectangles collide in both x, y and z directions, am I right? Perhaps you could check the shortest distance x-wise, y-wise and z-wise and limit that speed? Sorry for no better ideas :

Comment: Thanks for the response,Sara. It doesn't neccessary need to collide in all directions.It depends on which planes are intersecting.So if you have rectangles perpendicular to the coordinate system(not rotated),you would only have collision in one direction at a time, but when the rectangles are rotated it becomes more complicated. Then you might have collision in more than one direction at the same time. I cant find any good algorithm that will work for all varoius sizes of the rectangles.I have tried several ways of using Min Y, min x, max X, Y etc. in both conflicting rectangles, without luck.

Comment: Oh thats true! I hope somebody will give some hints :)